# UV map breaks in "Object mode"

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am a complete beginner using Blender, and I am following [this tutorial from CG Fast Track](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saxpjudV_88). It all works as expected up until the tutorial goes into the Shading chapter at 1h33m. The problem is this:

The UV texture on the object looks decent (I think) when I am in "Edit mode" like this:

[image]

but if I switch to "Object mode", it is messed up:

[image]

I have tried looking around as to why this happens, but it is beyond me at this point.

I dont think its doable to explain every setting and every number in the blender file that I have currently. Maybe someone knows what this might be, or, if someone finds the time and energy, here is the blender file and the texture images:

https://ufile.io/30nziz0m

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Oh, just after I posted this, I came to think of one thing the tutorial pointed out:
The order of the modifiers.

So, I tested to move the "Subdivision" modified up, so it is above "Bevel":

[image]

and after that, it looks OK in Object mode:

[image]